# Issue when java method annotated with @XmlTransient in Jaxb 2.1

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to annotate my java method as `@XmlTransient` in my java class like below.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class MyClass {

    @XmlTransient
    public void addsomething{

   // do something
    }

}
```

When I try to use this class in my JaxBContext through other class I am getting following exception

```
JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient()
```

,

But when I see `XmlTransient()` annotation definition`(@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,TYPE}))` it's clearly said be to work with methods. And In the JavaDoc(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html) it says

```
The @XmlTransient annotation can be used with the following program elements:

a JavaBean property
field
class
```

Can't I use `@XmlTransient` on methods?

Comment: no :) as Javadoc states you cannot do that

Comment: why you add `XmlTransient` to a `void` method ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only methods that `@XmlTransient` can be used are those that begin with `get` or `set`.  These methods used in combination are used to expose a property in Java.  `@XmlTransient` can be placed on either the `get` or `set` method.

**Get Method**

The get method must take no parameters and return a value:

```
public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

**Set Method**

The set method must take one parameter.

```
public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Comment: So in the `@XmlTransient` annotation definition `METHOD` means getter or setter of Java Bean property?

Comment: @SRy - That's right.  There is no annotation restriction for property so method needs to be used.